# sql presto query to join 2 tables interatably

Tags: mysql, presto

I need to do this in the sql query. LEt me know if this possible

I have a table which has a mapping like (table1)

```
num,value
2,'h'
3,'b'
5,'c'
```

Now I have another table which have these values (table2)

```
name, config
"test1",45
"test2",20
```

Now what I want is the sql query which will add another column to my  table2 by checking if config column values are divisible by table1.num and if yes concat the table1.values to it

so now after the sql query it should become

```
name, config, final
"test1",45, bc
"test2",20, hc
```

Please let me know if I can form a query for this

Comment: Are you using MySQL, or PrestoDB? The question is tagged with both, so it's unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can by using a cross join,the mod function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod and group_concat https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
select t2.name,t2.config,group_concat(t1.value separator '') final
from table1 t1
cross join table2 t2
where t2.config % t1.num = 0
group by t2.name,t2.config

+-------+--------+-------+
| name  | config | final |
+-------+--------+-------+
| test1 |     45 | bc    |
| test2 |     20 | hc    |
+-------+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from P.Salmon should work for MySQL. If you are using Presto, then this would work:

```
SELECT t2.name,
       t2.config,
       array_join(array_agg(t1.value),'','') AS final
FROM table1 t1
CROSS JOIN table2 t2
WHERE t2.config % t1.num = 0
GROUP BY t2.name,
         t2.config
```